# Two types of Users with one Login form - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, authentication

I'm working with ASP.NET Web applicaton and i'm completly lost with my project ! i have done so many methods but nothing has worked ! please i need someone to help me ! i have 2 types of tables (`Sellers` and `DevilryMen` ) now they are in tow separate tables (before they were in one table but everything went so wrong ! then i have decided to make it completely separate ) now i have finished the Registration page for both of them but my problem with the `Login` page ! i want to make one Login form for both but it didn't work ! could anyone please tell me if this is possible to make ? and how ? i know it's completely random question but i always end up delete everything and start again !

in case you need to look at my code :

1- `First_Home.aspx:`

```
<form id="form2">
<asp:Login ID = "Login1" runat = "server" OnAuthenticate= "ValidateUser" UseSubmitBehavior="False" ></asp:Login>
</form>
```

2-  `First_Home.aspx.cs:`  i have done a login for `Sellers` only

```
   protected void ValidateUser(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    int userId = 0;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Seller_Validate_User"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();
        }
        switch (userId)
        {
            case -1:
                Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                break;
            case -2:
                Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated.";
                break;
            default:
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
                break;
          }
     }
}
```

**UPDATE :** 
 Database Tables :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Email]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [UserType] INT           NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_Users_Email] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Email] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_Users_Username] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Username] ASC)
);    
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sellers] (
        [Seller_ID]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [Name]          NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        [SUsername]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        [Password]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        [SEmail]        NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        [Phone]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        [City]          NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        [LastLoginDate] DATETIME      NULL,
        [CreatedDate]   DATETIME      NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Seller_ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Sellers_Users_Username] FOREIGN KEY ([SUsername]) REFERENCES [Users]([Username]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Sellers_Users_Email] FOREIGN KEY ([SEmail]) REFERENCES [Users]([Email]),
    );
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeliveryMen] (
    [Delivery_ID]   INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]          NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [DUsername]      NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [Password]      NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [DEmail]         NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [Phone]         NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [City]          NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [License]       VARBINARY (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Delivery_ID] ASC), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_DeliveryMen_Users_Username] FOREIGN KEY ([DUsername]) REFERENCES [Users]([Username]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_DeliveryMen_Users_Email] FOREIGN KEY ([DEmail]) REFERENCES [Users]([Email]),
```

Comment: Why not set some kind of boolean that tells the method whether or not a delivey man is signing in or a seller?

Comment: It seems that the trouble you are having is actually an overabundance of options. The best way was your original choice though. You want one table for logins. You'll probably want to also have a table for both sellers and delivery men. If a login ID is in one of those other two tables then it means they are one (or both if it is in both). Also, that `CheckBoxList2` field looks like something you really should ask another question about (there is a much better way to achieve what you want (which can be queried later, easily)).

Comment: @code i did it before but still didn't work !

Comment: This is definitely in need of some redesign IMHO. Too much repetition of fields. You could have a `User`s table and have these inherit from a user.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils @Krowe i have done a `Users` Table only for Login and the other tables was inherit as well but i had a lot of errors with FKs maybe my way was wrong ! i will update my code before with `Users` Table .. please check it

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils i have update my post

Comment: That's not the way I would do it. Why not simply have a `UserId` in the Seller and Deliverymen? You can authenticate `Users` and display content to specific type users based on the id. User table should have all the fields common to both Seller and Deliverymen - username, password, email, phone, and city and should not be repeated in the specific tables.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils so you mean i have to do a new registration form connected with `Users` and have the common fields then do the same login code i have done but with `Users` table right ? so what can be the FKs ? and i should have a `checkbox` to specify the type of the users right ? i tried it but i think my way was too wrong :(

Comment: The reg page doesn't really matter. You've got that working sounds like and are concerned about the login. The login will check for username and password (attributes of a user). And you can get the user id; right? So you allow them to login with those fields, then, if authorized, you would use that id to get the Seller or Delivery from appropriate table by user type and redirect them to their profile page for example with the complete data. There's many ways to do it so I think you should clean up the tables try to do it and update your post with the errors you're getting. FK = user_id